# NGINX causing Authorization Issues

Tags: nginx, apache2

Ive been using Apache for a while with Prestashop and have been able to access the API no problem using a Third Party Service (Go Sweet Spot), they authorize using a call webservicekey@domainname.com. Ive also replicated this configuration locally and it works 100% both using the above method and using a query string parameter domainname.com?ws_key=webservicekey (Also works on server but isn't available from Go Sweet Spot).

However I recently installed Plesk Onyx on a new server and cannot connect using the default third party authorization technique. the Query string will work but not the webservicekey@domainname.com technique - it will continuosly ask for input however the key is the username and there is no password so authorization can't be achieved (worked on previous server and on local development server one Apache the other Apache+Varnish). I'm quite certain that this is an issue caused by NGINX or enforced by NGINX or Apache configuration, and to be honest I'm not sure what the authorization technique is called to Google for a solution.

Is anybody able to help?
Thank you

Comment: Could you share your development/previous server config, and maybe provide the Apache or nginx version from both the old and new servers? It might also help to edit the question with a bit more detail - you mention Apache, nginx, and varnish, can you explain what each is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this had nothing to do with NGINX, it was due to PHP-FPM which I didn't have enabled on the previous web servers

To solve, edit .htaccess and add just after

RewriteEngine on

the code:

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

pd: if you have the file htaccess.conf on conf folder you must edit this file and add the code.